# Before conditional for multiple instance methods in a rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, ruby-on-rails-4, instance-methods

I have several methods in my rails model that basically check the same before conditional before running their code so that when I run

```
obj = new Model
obj.method1(args)
```

It will run the before method. I am aware that I could use before_action with rails, however I am not sure how to make the before action a conditional, meaning if the before_action fails, do not proceed.

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  def before_method(args)
    #do stuff
  end
  def method1(args)
    if before_method(args)
      #do stuff
    end
  end
  def method2(args)
    if before_method(args)
      #do stuff
    end
  end
  def method3(args)
    if before_method(args)
      #do stuff
    end
  end
  def method4(args)
    if before_method(args)
      #do stuff
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: A `before_action` has a very specific use case: methods in controllers. Is this a controller?

Comment: No this is in a model. @tokland

Comment: If you're not opposed to using them, Active Record Callbacks will handle this for you. guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html